# How to add class active in sequence?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a set of `path` elements and these paths have classes that i am checking if they match a `condition`, each time this `condition` is matched, a class `active` needs to be added to it

```
mapMatch(list);

function mapMatch(list) {
  $("svg path").removeClass("active");
  $("svg path").each(function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      space = list[i].Space.replace(" ", "_");
      space = space.replace("[Image]\u00a0", "");
      if($(this).attr('class').split(" ")[0] == space) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          $(this).addClass("active");
        }, 1000);
      } 
    }; 
  });
}
```

The code above isn't adding the class tho, nor it is adding it in sequence. ideally I'd like a colour fill change animation via css, the following will apply it straight forward instead.

```
path.active {
  fill: #ff4d4a;
}
```

If I do the following, it'd work but with no sequence:

```
function mapMatch(list) {
  $("svg path").removeClass("active");
  $("svg path").each(function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      space = list[i].Space.replace(" ", "_");
      space = space.replace("[Image]\u00a0", "");
      if($(this).attr('class').split(" ")[0] == space) {
        $(this).addClass("active");
      } 
    }; 
  });
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "sequence"?

Comment: the class active adds a color fill, so if I give the class all together to each path, I won't see a sequence colour change, I'd like them to change colour one after the one while matching

Comment: You mean you want an animation during a period of a second or so, and not all at once?

Comment: yes exactly @trincot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class is not added in the first version of your code because `this` is not what you think it is. The callback that you provide to `setTimeout` will have `this` bound to the global object (or `undefined` if in strict mode). Solve this by binding `this` (or use an arrow function):

```
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(this).addClass("active");
    }.bind(this), 1000);
```

To get the animation effect, you should increase the delay depending on *i*:

```
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(this).addClass("active");
    }.bind(this), 1000 * i);
```

If the class should be applied at different times for the outer `each` loop as well, then introduce another counter:

```
function mapMatch(list) {
  var j = 0; /// <------
  $("svg path").removeClass("active");
  $("svg path").each(function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      space = list[i].Space.replace(" ", "_");
      space = space.replace("[Image]\u00a0", "");
      if($(this).attr('class').split(" ")[0] == space) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          $(this).addClass("active");
        }.bind(this), 1000 * j++); /// <----
      } 
    }; 
  });
}
```

Comment: is it not bind deprecated? using jquery v3

Comment: This is not the jQuery `bind`, but the JavaScript [`Function#bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method.